# Only one of multiple views fails with findViewById()

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to reference a TextView from a layout. It works for all other views but for this specific one it returns null. Doing it the same way for all the views, so I can't see why it wouldn't work on this one.

Important to mention is that the layout file showed here is included into b_user_list. All views referenced from within the include works, except for one.

b_user_list.xml:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/showUserLay"
    layout="@layout/c_show_front_layout"
    ... />
```

c_show_front_layout.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/volunDbListLay" 
    ... >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView932"
        ... />
    
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider522"
        ... />
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/volunDbRecycler"
        ... />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noVolunOrgsFound"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No organizations found."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/volunDbRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/volunDbRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/volunDbRecycler"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/volunDbRecycler" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActivityUser.java:

```
private ConstraintLayout settErrorLay; 
private TextView errorTxt; 
private TextView errorClose;

private TextView noVolunOrgsFound;
private RecyclerView volunDbRecycler;
private ConstraintLayout volunDbListLay, notVsAccWarning;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_user_list);

    ...

    settErrorLay = findViewById(R.id.userIntegrErrorLay);
    errorClose = findViewById(R.id.closeUserIntegrErrorTxt);

    ...


    if (errorClose != null && settErrorLay != null) { 
        // Checks if includeView show_front_layout.xml worked

        volunDbRecycler = findViewById(R.id.volunDbRecycler);
        volunDbListLay = findViewById(R.id.volunDbListLay);
        notVsAccWarning = findViewById(R.id.notVsAccWarning);
        noVolunOrgsFound = findViewById(R.id.noVolunOrgsFound);

        ...
    }

    ...
}

...
```

I found a way to reference the view, but obviously not the proper way. I ran through all the children of the parent view, and when the id match I add it as the view. Then it didn't return null:

```
if (noVolunOrgsFound == null) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < volunDbListLay.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (volunDbListLay.getChildAt(i).getId() == R.id.noVolunOrgsFound) {
            noVolunOrgsFound = (TextView) volunDbListLay.getChildAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So I have ran out of ideas for why this doesn't work. It can't be the <include> since the other sibling views works, the id is the same both in the layout and java, and it works with by finding it within the children of the parent, just not with findViewById().

**EDIT**: I posted an answer that seemed to be solving the problem, but now I just have the same problem with a RecyclerView. This time, it didn't work to manually loop through the views of the parent and checking when the child view id match the RecyclerView's id..

Is there a limit to how many views can be loaded or referenced in Java or something?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I left out something in the question that I didn't think would have a say in the matter (And I'm still not sure why it does).

Before the `findViewById(R.id.noVolunOrgsFound);` was a function, and in that function was a button assigned to use the TextView (the one that was null). Not sure how the button makes the TextView null, but apparently it did.

```
initializeDbSettingsLay();

volunDbRecycler = findViewById(R.id.volunOrgRecycler);
volunDbListLay = findViewById(R.id.volunOrgListLay);
notVsAccWarning = findViewById(R.id.notVsAccWarning);
noVolunOrgsFound = findViewById(R.id.noVolunOrgsFound);
```

Moving the function after the `findViewById(R.id.noVolunOrgsFound);`, it now wasn't null anymore. Not sure why the button either made it null or not properly find the view, since it worked on the other layouts that also is used in that button function. Only the TextView became null. I'd like to say that the TextView can't be assigned after the ClickListener has been created, but generally values can be changed later, and so did the other views. So I'm not sure why it failed with the TextView.

Here is the function:

```
private void initializeDbSettingsLay() {

    ...

    vsSettingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            userSettingsBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            dbSettingsBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            vsSettingsBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ActivityUser.this.getColor(R.color.slight_gray)));
            userSettingsLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dbSettingsLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vsSettingsLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            learnMoreVsLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            learnMoreVsBtn.setText("Learn more");


            if (currentUserModel == null || currentUserModel.getVolunAccount() == null) {
                volunDbListLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notVsAccWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

                volunDbListLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notVsAccWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadVolunOrgList();
            }
        }
    });

    ...

}


private void loadVolunOrgList() {

    if (currentUserModel == null || currentUserModel.getVolunAccount() == null || currentUserModel.getOrgsList() == null || currentUserModel.getOrgsList().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }


    List<OrganisationModel> orgList = currentUserModel.getOrgDataList();

    if (orgList.size() == 0) {
        noVolunOrgsFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return;
    }


    noVolunOrgsFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Removing both noVolunOrgsFound.setVisibility() above from this function, the rest of the code then worked \/

    UserIntegrAdapter orgAdapter = new UserIntegrAdapter(orgList, this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    volunDbRecycler.setAdapter(orgAdapter);
    volunDbRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityUser.this));
}
```